# Можно ли вывести превью загружаемой картинки?

Tags: php, изображения, upload

Можно как то вывести превью загружаемой картинки ? Миниатюру, где красный квадра.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459379/preview-an-image-before-it-is-uploaded

Answer (score 0):

Форма отправки у вас уже есть. Я приведу свой скрипт который использую(не поню где его нашел), правда для него, вам надо подключить jquery.

```js
 var previewWidth = 150, // ширина превью
        previewHeight = 150, // высота превью
        maxFileSize = 2 * 1024 * 1024, // (байт) Максимальный размер файла (2мб)
        selectedFiles = {},// объект, в котором будут храниться выбранные файлы
        queue = [],
        image = new Image(),
        imgLoadHandler,
        isProcessing = false,
        errorMsg, // сообщение об ошибке при валидации файла
        previewPhotoContainer = document.querySelector('#preview-photo'); // контейнер, в котором будут отображаться превью
 
    // Когда пользователь выбрал файлы, обрабатываем их
    $('input[type=file][id=photo]').on('change', function() {
        var newFiles = $(this)[0].files; // массив с выбранными файлами
 
        for (var i = 0; i < newFiles.length; i++) {
 
            var file = newFiles[i];
 
            // В качестве "ключей" в объекте selectedFiles используем названия файлов
            // чтобы пользователь не мог добавлять один и тот же файл
            // Если файл с текущим названием уже существует в массиве, переходим к следующему файлу
            if (selectedFiles[file.name] != undefined) continue;
 
            // Валидация файлов (проверяем формат и размер)
            if ( errorMsg = validateFile(file) ) {
                alert(errorMsg);
                return;
            }
 
            // Добавляем файл в объект selectedFiles
            selectedFiles[file.name] = file;
            queue.push(file);
 
        }
 
        $(this).val('');
        processQueue(); // запускаем процесс создания миниатюр
    });
 
    // Валидация выбранного файла (формат, размер)
    var validateFile = function(file)
    {
        if ( !file.type.match(/image\/(jpeg|jpg|png|gif)/) ) {
            return 'Фотография должна быть в формате jpg, png или gif';
        }
 
        if ( file.size > maxFileSize ) {
            return 'Размер фотографии не должен превышать 2 Мб';
        }
    };
 
    var listen = function(element, event, fn) {
        return element.addEventListener(event, fn, false);
    };
 
    // Создание миниатюры
    var processQueue = function()
    {
        // Миниатюры будут создаваться поочередно
        // чтобы в один момент времени не происходило создание нескольких миниатюр
        // проверяем запущен ли процесс
        if (isProcessing) { return; }
 
        // Если файлы в очереди закончились, завершаем процесс
        if (queue.length == 0) {
            isProcessing = false;
            return;
        }
 
        isProcessing = true;
 
        var file = queue.pop(); // Берем один файл из очереди
 
        var li = document.createElement('LI');
        var span = document.createElement('SPAN');
        var spanDel = document.createElement('SPAN');
        var canvas = document.createElement('CANVAS');
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
 
        span.setAttribute('class', 'img');
        spanDel.setAttribute('class', 'delete');
        spanDel.innerHTML = 'Удалить';
 
        li.appendChild(span);
        li.appendChild(spanDel);
        li.setAttribute('data-id', file.name);
 
        image.removeEventListener('load', imgLoadHandler, false);
 
        // создаем миниатюру
        imgLoadHandler = function() {
            ctx.drawImage(image, 0, 0, previewWidth, previewHeight);
            URL.revokeObjectURL(image.src);
            span.appendChild(canvas);
            isProcessing = false;
            setTimeout(processQueue, 200); // запускаем процесс создания миниатюры для следующего изображения
        };
 
        // Выводим миниатюру в контейнере previewPhotoContainer
        previewPhotoContainer.appendChild(li);
        listen(image, 'load', imgLoadHandler);
        image.src = URL.createObjectURL(file);
 
        // Сохраняем содержимое оригинального файла в base64 в отдельном поле формы
        // чтобы при отправке формы файл был передан на сервер
        var fr = new FileReader();
        fr.readAsDataURL(file);
        fr.onload = (function (file) {
            return function (e) {
                $('#preview-photo').append(
                        '<input type="hidden" name="photos[]" value="' + e.target.result + '" data-id="' + file.name+ '">'
                );
            }
        }) (file);
    };
 
    // Удаление фотографии
    $(document).on('click', '#preview-photo li span.delete', function() {
        var fileId = $(this).parents('li').attr('data-id');
 
        if (selectedFiles[fileId] != undefined) delete selectedFiles[fileId]; // Удаляем файл из объекта selectedFiles
        $(this).parents('li').remove(); // Удаляем превью
        $('input[name^=photo][data-id="' + fileId + '"]').remove(); // Удаляем поле с содержимым файла
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="post">
 
    <div>
        <input type="file" multiple="" id="photo">
    </div>
    <div>
        <ul id="preview-photo">
        </ul>
    </div>
 
</form>
```